# IIS 8.5 reverse proxy redirect

Tags: meteor, reverse-proxy, adfs2.0, iis-8.5

I hava a meteor application running on windows server 2012 r2.
I need my app to run over ssl so i set the meteor to port 80 and created a reverse proxy in the iis from 443 to 80 (i deactivated port 80 on the iis).

All works fine until i want to redirect the user to the ADFS server for authentication. the url that the client get is with the app name (the server) and not the ADFS url. -> what happen is that the iis change the url from the adfs server to the app server.

In order to configure the iis reverse proxy i use this guide: http://www.myconnectionserver.com/support/tutorials/v90/iisProxy/index.html

Does someone has any idea how to configure iis properly?